Python Kivy & Buildozer : How remove the Kivy logo and message "loading ..."
I've built a little application that works just as well on PC as it does on Android (nothing complicated; the application is excessively simple).
Everything works fine on my android and on my debian and windows. On the other hand, I have an esthetic problem on Android.
When I launch the application, it displays the Kivy logo and a “loading ...” message.
I'm in the latest version of buildozer, kivy and python and while searching on Google (old articles) I'm told that I need to change the buildozer.spec file but none of the proposed solutions work.
Do you have any ideas? Is it still possible?

Customize Splash Screen (Optional): If you want to create a custom splash screen, you can create a new layout and use it to display your logo or message while the app initializes. For example, you can use Kivy's ScreenManager to control this behavior. Here's a simple example:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class SplashScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Add a custom image or message to the splash screen
        self.add_widget(Image(source='your_splash_image.png'))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.change_screen, 3)  # Wait 3 seconds before changing screen

    def change_screen(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = 'main_screen'

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(SplashScreen(name='splash'))
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main_screen'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

This code shows a custom splash screen for 3 seconds before transitioning to the main screen.
Rebuild the Application: After making the changes to the buildozer.spec file, you need to rebuild the application by running:
buildozer android debug

This should remove the Kivy logo and "loading..." message or allow you to customize the startup screen.

what you propose is to add an extra screen on my app; what I'm talking about is the splashscreen directly added by buildozer/kiwi at the beginning ... I've test your code and I have now the Kivy Loading, then 3s for my picture and then my app :( Is there something to modify on the buildozer itself ?

Ok I found the solution (I'm stupid ^^ )
Here are the actions I've follow

open the buildozer.desc
add presplash.filename = yourfile.png (and not presplash.file as I've done since days ... you know why I'm stupid now)
add android.presplash_color= black (or any color you want)

and compile ...
Sorry for my stupid questions :(
